# Send multi data JS object through Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, image, upload

I'm trying to collect string values and images from my form and append them to my JS object. I have no issues with the string values, but when I put the binary data into the JS object, it's always empty

HTML:

```
<div class="form-section">

<div class="form-element">
 <input class="upl-img" type="file" />
</div>

<div class="form-element">

</div>
<div class="form-element">
 <input class="upl-img" type="file" />
</div>

</div>
```

JS:

```
  function buildMyFormSection(){

   formElement = {
   options = {
   ---
   elemImage : getFormImage(this.closest($('#image-field'))[0].files[0]),
   -----
    }

    }

   }
   function getFormImage(imgInput){
   var img = {};

   var file = imgInput;
   var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload(function(e){

   img.name = imgInput.name;
   img.data = e.target.result;

   console.log(e.target.result);

   });

   reader.readAsDataURL(imgInput);

   return img;

   }
```

getFormImage function returns the desired data, but the elemImage above always shows me "{}" as value.

Comment: By the time you return `img` from `getFormImage`, it's not set with any data yet - `onload` callback is not called. I would restructure it in a way to use deferreds, like [here](https://gist.github.com/jollytoad/4201905). And when that deferred is resolved, you should set your `formElement`.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with deferreds, but I wonder if I could do it like this:<pre>     function getFormImage(field) {
          var deferred = $.Deferred();
          var img = {};
          var file = field;
          var reader = new FileReader();
          reader.readAsDataURL(file);
          $.when(

          reader.onload(function(e) {
          img.name = file.name;
          img.data = e.target.result;

          });

    )then(function() {
        deferred.resolve(img);

        return deferred.promise();

    }).done(function(data) {


        return data;
    });


}<pre>